# FEA with order reduced for a large system with a very localized force application

Tags: finite-element, reduced-order-modeling

I have a large structure with many DOFs. But the application of force is very localized say over one or two nodes. If I try to run FEA on this with Guyan Reduction, I think the efficiency of reduction would be very less.

The stiffness matrix can be partitioned into master and slave stiffness matrices: 
$K = \begin{bmatrix}
     K_{mm} & K_{ms} \\
     K_{sm} & K_{ss} 
     \end{bmatrix}$

Now in my scenario, $K_{ss}$ will be very large and we have to invert it anyhow to get the reduced stiffness matrix: 
$K_{reduced} = K_{mm} - K_{ms} K_{ss}^{-1} K_{sm}$

Is there any condensation techniques to avoid this and how to implement it for this kind of problem?

Comment: A technique to avoid *what*? Inverting $K_{ss}$?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Yes, because size of $K_{ss}$ is as big as $K$ itself.

Comment: In that case, just don't invert $K_{ss}$ and solve with all of $K$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $m$ is a small number compared to $s$, you do not need to invert $K_{ss}$ to calculate the Schur complement.

You just need to calculate all $m$ columns of the $s\times m$ matrix $K_{ss}^{-1}K_{sm}$ by solving $m$ linear systems with $K_{ss}$ as the system matrix, and each column of the $K_{sm}$ matrix as the right-hand-side.